# Turing machine for unary subtraction $m-n$. If $m<n$, the machine writes "$!$" $|m-n|$ times

Tags: turing-machines, computability, automata

I am trying to program a Turing machine that performs unary subtraction, $m-n$, but if $m<n$, the machine writes the $!$ symbol on the tape $|m-n|$ times. If $m=1$ and $n=3$, the machine would only leave $!!$ on the tape.

Now, I have successfully created a machine that performs unary subtraction $m-n$ where $m<n$ and it looks like this:

[image]

It utilizes a leap-frog technique, where I subtract $|$ from the beginning of the first number, then subtract $|$ from the end of the second number in each pass. One thing to note is that we are using a Turing machine model that when writing onto the tape, **the head of the machine does not to move left or right**, as seen for example in the transition from $q_0$ to $q_0$.

My question is: Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Do I need to built another machine, or can I somehow modify this one to fit my needs. If so, can anyone tell me roughly how?